# Configuring a slave's hostname using internal IP - Multiple NICs

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

In my Hadoop environment, I need to configure my slave nodes so that when they communicate in the middle of a map/reduce job they use the internal IP instead of the external IP that it picks up from the hostname.

Is there any way to set up my Hadoop config files to specify that the nodes should communicate using the internal IPs instead of the external IPs? I've already used the internal IPs in my core-site.xml, master, and slave files.

I've done some research and I've seen people mention the "slave.host.name" parameter, but which config file would I place this parameter in? Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `IP routing tables` have to be changed so that the network between the Hadoop nodes uses a particular gateway. Don't think Hadoop has any setting to change which gateway to use.

Comment: is there no other way to do this?

if so is there a simple way to set the IP routing tables so that it only returns the internal IP if it's a specific node/ip requesting it?

Comment: You can use the `route` command - open another query on how to change ip routing and someone will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can configured slave.host.name in mapred-site.xml for each slave node. 
Also remember to use that host name (instead of IP) consistently for all other configurations (core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, masters, slaves) and also /etc/hosts file.